# How to identify that compiler variable value is not a default value?

Tags: install4j

How to check in a script that compiler variable was modified and has value other than default one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiler variables are not modifiable, only installer variables can be modified. You can have compiler variables and installer variables with the same name.

Comment: I mean you have default values defined at the _General Settings > Compiler Variables_. Then you can override those values at the _Customize project defaults > Compiler variables_ of the Media. The question is: can we programmatically determine if the overridden value differs from the default one? Install4j has a special icon when the default value is overridden.

Comment: No, unfortunately there's no way to determine that at runtime.